# System.Xml.XmlException DTD is prohibited in this XML document Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to do SSO through ADFS while passing the URL through `IDpSsoDescriptor`. Issue I am facing:

> System.Xml.XmlException   HResult=0x80131940   Message=For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.   Source=ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2   StackTrace:

I have tried:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
```

But not possible to edit methods in `dll`.